# Listing: line numbering in a two column document class

Tags: listings, two-column, code, matlab

With the following code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0}
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=Matlab,
    basicstyle=\small,
    breaklines=true,
    morekeywords={matlab2tikz},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},%
    morekeywords=[2]{1}, keywordstyle=[2]{\color{black}},
    identifierstyle=\color{black},%
    stringstyle=\color{mylilas},
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},%
    showstringspaces=false,%
    numbers=left,%
    numberstyle={\tiny \color{black}},% size of the numbers
    numbersep=9pt, % this defines how far the numbers are from the text
    emph=[1]{for,end,break},emphstyle=[1]\color{red},
}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \lstinputlisting{GiveMeAnAnswerPlease.m}
\end{document}
```

The code come from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75124/38435). Here the output:
[image: the output]
Unfortunately line numbering overlays the first column. Is it possible to shift the line numbering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set for example

```
xleftmargin=2em
```

in the `\lstset` command.